# error 500 on simple htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the next .htaccess file in my web project.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-l



#RewriteLogLevel 9

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ods|odt|doc?x|xls|pdf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|less|xml|gz)$ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 here
```

And this always was worked fine, but today my hosting service did some change (I think) and now i have a 500 error on my web.
I contacted to them, and they told me that the web site has the next error log.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Can somebody tell me what can i do to fix it? I saw in other post that probably my RewriteRule can be better, but i don't know.

Thanks.

PD: Sorry, my english is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rewrite rule is unconditionally rewriting all requests to /index.php because of invalid RewriteConds. to change this behaviour just Remove the "%" from the test strings :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l



#RewriteLogLevel 9

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ods|odt|doc?x|xls|pdf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|less|xml|gz)$ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answered. I did what you say, (tecnically copy and paste), but then, the web show me the next errors:  
**Notice: Undefined index: url .... on line 97**  
**Notice:  Undefined index: url in....on line 100**,  

like the **RewriteRule**, has been ignored now.  
Addicionally, if I put something more in the url like domain.com/something the server show me 404 Not found error, He does not redirecting to index.